# Allow all external users with a specific domain to SharePoint site

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, sharepoint

My client runs 2 companies, lets call them X and Y. They have their own office 365 setups, so accounts from company Y are treated as external users by X's SharePoint sites. I would have to grant access to every account separately.

Is it possible to automatically allow users with a specific domain to access one of the sites?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enrolled in the [SharePoint and OneDrive integration with Azure AD B2B](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-azureb2b-integration), you may set domain restrictions, more detailed informtion, please refer to "[Allow or block invitations to B2B users from specific organizations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/allow-deny-list)" and "[External sharing overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview)".

For individual file sharing in SharePoint Online, please refer to "[Restrict sharing of SharePoint and OneDrive content by domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/restricted-domains-sharing)".